# Websocket fails with 500 using AWS Application Load Balancer and beanstalk

Tags: .net-core, amazon-ec2, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

- I used to use AWS beanstalk without any custom network configuration, so all my applications were able to call each other without any network issues as they are in a default public network setup.
  whenever I am trying to put them in a custom network setup, the WebSocket feature gets missed however it is already supported by the ALB and worked fine before.
- my application is a chatbot application based on .net core, the internal service uses a web socket in private subnets with its load balancer, and is called by another service in public subnets in the same vpc.
  an obvious indication that the WebSocket works is the live update of messages in the internal service dashboard, but now I am facing an issue retrieving the messages lively, I should refresh the page to get the latest updates.
- I have checked the network reach-ability among all services and was able to resolve domains and process requests normally,
  also, using the browser inspection, I can see only two requests that fail with 500
  [check failed requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW7J1.png)
- I have checked security groups for ec2 instances and the load balancer as well, and all are configured properly:
- ec2 instances security group:
  [check inbound ec2 security group rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTg7i.png)
  outbound opened for all traffic
- ALB security group:
  [check inbound ALB security group rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PprxX.png)
  and outbound opened for all traffic
- I have checked if the issue in ALB as it may not support websocket but after a wide search, I found that the new version of ALB supports WebSocket natively with the HTTP/2 protocol version, and as the WebSocket was working fine before creating the custom network, I don't need to touch load balancer configs.
  [check ALB configs for websocket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwNdT.png)

**Logs**:

unfortunately, logs didn't help me so much as it refers to errors that unrelated to websocket issue

- beanstalk logs for internal service:
  [check beanstalk logs in this drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E3cJqFszatjYd8U2ubfQPwpZ3-EUzQ4I/view?usp=sharing)
- beanstalk logs for public service:
  [check beanstalk logs in this drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YpgS7i0IilyD8T87idMQBeuxL0d18bnF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please check .NET application logs and share some insight you can see there

Comment: @michail_w   i have updated the question with a new section for logs

Comment: I can't see any .NET logs in the public service file. Do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off HTTP/2. ALB supports websockets and it supports HTTP/2, but I can't find anything indicating that it supports websockets over HTTP/2, which isn't an officially supported part of the HTTP/2 or HTTP/3 protocols yet (There are proposals for both and some webservers have implemented it)